# $f(|z|)$ is not an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

Let $f: [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a non constant function. Define $g:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ by $g(z)=f(|z|)$. Prove that $g(z)$ is not holomorphic.

So, I need to find a point $z_0$ where it is not analytic.

Write $f(x)=u(x)+iv(x)$ then $f(|z|)=u(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+iv(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.

Set $p(x,y)=u(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ and $q(x,y)=v(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$

Then, $$\partial p/\partial x=(\partial u/\partial x)(x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}),\partial p/\partial y=(\partial u/\partial y)(y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$
and  $$\partial q/\partial x=(\partial v/\partial x)(x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}),\partial q/\partial y=(\partial v/\partial y)(y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$$

Suppose it is holomorphic then it has to satisfy cauchy riemann equations and so we should have
$$x(\partial u/\partial x)=y(\partial v/\partial y),y(\partial u/\partial y)=-x(\partial v/\partial x)$$

After writing this then i realized that $u,v$ are functions of single variable.. It does not make sense in trying to differentiate with two variables...

I am clueless at this stage.

Comment: If $f(x)=x$, can you prove it?

Comment: Yes i can. we then have $g(x+iy)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $v(x,y)=0$.. Supposing it is holomorphic it has to satisfy  cauchy riemann equations.. So, we shoudl have $\partial u/partial x=\partial v/\partial y=0$ for instance which is same as $x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=0 $ for all $x$ which is not true.. So, $g(z)=f(|z|)$ when $f(x)=x$ is not holomorphic @RickSanchez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different approach that uses a little bit of complex analysis. Suppose that $g$ is entire (analytic on $\mathbb{C}$). Then on the unit circle, $g$ is constantly equal to $f(1)$. As the unit circle has a limit point in $\mathbb{C}$, and since $\mathbb{C}$ is connected, $g(z)=f(1)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$. This implies $f(t)=g(t)=f(1)$ for all $t \geq 0$, so $f$ is constant.

Comment: This is a complex analysis question so i expect it to use some complex analysis.. On $\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$ we have $g(z)=f(|z|)=f(1)$ constant.. Fine.. Consider function $h(z)=g(z)-1$.. Zero set of this has a limit point.. Thus $g(z)=1$ i.e., $f(t)=f(1)$ for all $t\geq 0$.. Perfect...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $g$ is holomorphic. Fix a $z\ne0$ and consider the auxiliary function
$$\psi(t):=g\bigl(e^{it}z\bigr)\qquad(t\in{\mathbb R})\ ,$$
which is in fact constant. It follows that
$$\psi'(t)=g'\bigl(e^{it}z\bigr)\>ize^{it}\equiv0\ ,$$
and putting $t=0$ here implies $g'(z)=0$. It would follow that $$f'(x)=g'(x)\equiv0\qquad(x>0)\ ,$$
contrary to assumption about $f$.

Comment: We are assuming that $f$ is differentiable.. what can we say about the case when $f$ is any arbitrary function..

Comment: I'm not assuming that $f$ is differentiable a priori. But if $g$ is holomorphic and $g(x)=f(x)$ for $x>0$ then $f$ has to be differentiable as a function of $x\in{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: It seems fine but i am not very comfortable with the idea of mixing real and complex functions.. MAy be i need some time to think. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to the solution. Choose $z=x+iy$ on a circle with radius $r$: $|z|=r$. Then you get
$$
x\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r) = y\frac{\partial v}{\partial r}(r) 
$$
If $z$ runs over the circle the derivatives in the equation above are always the same, but $x$ and $y$ vary. If you choose $x=r,y=0$ and $x=0,y=r$ you get
$$
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(r) = \frac{\partial v}{\partial r}(r) = 0
$$
Hence $u=const.$ and $v=const.$ and $f$ must be constant.

Comment: Oh yes.. Changing two variables case into one variable case. This does make sense.. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't think f is assumed differentiable.

Comment: Yes that is also one of the issues... @RickSanchez

Comment: @Rick Sanchez : You can assume $g$ is holomorphic, which implies that $f$ is smooth by restricting $g$ to an open ray ; the above implies that $f$ is constant.